# tikz yshift not work with a evaluated offset

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to use yshift to draw some lines by a offset from evaluate result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\dx{2cm}
    \def\dy{2}
    \node (L1) {L1};
    \node[right=\dx of L1] (L2) {L2};
    \node[right=\dx of L2] (L3) {L3};
    \foreach \from/\to/\desc [count=\i from 1,evaluate=\i as \y using {-\i*\dy} ] in {
        L1/L2/A,
        L2/L3/B,
        L3/L1/C
    } {
        \draw[->] ([yshift=\y]\from) -- ([yshift=\y]\to) node[midway,label=above:\desc] (N\i) {};
    }
    \foreach \x in {L1,L2,L3} {
        \draw[line width=2pt] (\x) -- (\x |- N\i);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But sounds like the yshfit behavior is abnormal:

[image]

Comment: `\dy` does not have units, so the shift is interpreted in points, and it would be cleaner to apply the shift to an anchor, e.g. `\draw[->] ([yshift=\y]\from.south) -- ([yshift=\y]\to.south) node[midway,label=above:\desc] (N\i) {};`. BTW, `\foreach \x in {L1,L2,L3} {` misses a `[count=\i from 0]`, so should really be `\foreach \x [count=\i from 0] in {L1,L2,L3} {`, or something that defines `\i`. Also I do not quite see what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this go in the right direction? I was trying to read between the lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\dx{2cm}
    \def\dy{2pt}
    \node (L1) {L1};
    \node[right=\dx of L1] (L2) {L2};
    \node[right=\dx of L2] (L3) {L3};
    \foreach \from/\to/\desc [count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as \y using {7-\i*\dy} ] in {
        L1/L2/A,
        L2/L3/B,
        L3/L1/C
    } {
        \draw[-stealth,shorten >=1pt] ([yshift=\y]\from.north) -- ([yshift=\y]\to.north) node[midway,label=above:\desc] (N\i) {};
    }
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0] in {L1,L2,L3} {
        \draw[line width=2pt,shorten >=-1.5pt] (\x) -- (\x |- N\ifnum\i=0 \i\else\the\numexpr\i-1\fi);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that's what I want if change dy from 2pt to 2cm. we should use anchor to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

shift command is for coordinate, not for node. Schrödinger's cat's answer is awesome.I guess it's for a simple UML sequence diagram drawings. Add a new version with more better output:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\dx{2cm}
    \def\dy{0.5cm}
    \node (L1) {L1};
    \node[right=\dx of L1] (L2) {L2};
    \node[right=\dx of L2] (L3) {L3};
    \foreach \from/\to/\desc [count=\i from 1,evaluate=\i as \y using {-\i*\dy} ] in {
        L1/L2/A,
        L2/L3/B,
        L3/L1/C
    } {
        \draw[-stealth,shorten >=1pt] ([yshift=\y]\from.south) -- ([yshift=\y]\to.south) node[midway,label=above:\desc] (N\i) {};
    }
    \foreach \x in {L1,L2,L3} {
        \draw[line width=2pt,shorten >=-2pt] (\x) -- (\x |- N\i);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]